# react router dom trailing slash gives error instead of going to 404 page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using a `react-router-dom` via `Route` component. Everything works fine, including if a page doesn't exist, then the app goes to a 404 page. All good, until I add a slash at the end of a url and the screen goes blank with 404 errors in the `console`. For example, this `http://localhost/random` doesn't exist and goes to a 404 page but as if I do `http://localhost/random/ <--- this slash`, it breaks everything. What I expect is for this url to also go to 404 page or go to an existing page:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/path-extra">
    <Redirect to="/path-redirected" />
  </Route>
  <Route
    path="/path-one"
    component={PathOne}
  />
  <Route
    path="/path-two"
    component={PathTwo}
  />
  <Route render={() => <RoutingError errorCode="404" />} />
</Switch>
```

The error I receive in the console, if I type `http://localhost/random/`:

`GET http://localhost/js/main.5d5472a1.bundle.js?f6bb2549a0dc1a3342b0 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

Is there a way to make sure that any path, whether with a slash at the end or not, doesn't break anything and act accordingly?

Comment: "it breaks everything" — What does that mean? https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Comment: [This any help](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/03/23/react-router-remove-trailing-slash-from-urls)?

Comment: Are you sure that your webserver returns the same page for any path?

Comment: @Quentin, "breaks everything" means the app isn't working with errors in the console, and the browser is blank.

Comment: There are errors? What errors? See also [ask]

Comment: @Quentin, this error, `GET http://localhost/js/main.5d5472a1.bundle.js?f6bb2549a0dc1a3342b0 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`. Let me update the question.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the similar issue and found out that i had missed adding public path in webpack config.
Adding public path helps webpack to understand the root of our project. Following fix worked for me:

```
output: { publicPath: '/' }
```